# Understanding why strace shows the parent PID being returned in getpid()

Tags: linux, system-calls, strace

I'm puzzled by some strace captures that I got running strace. Here are the relevant lines:

```
[pid 170039] 03:21:51 clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f89ee4b8210) = 171280
...
[pid 171280] 03:21:51 getppid( <unfinished ...>
[pid 171280] 03:21:51 <... getppid resumed>) = 170039
...
[pid 171280] 03:22:12 clone(child_stack=0x7faa47ffaf30, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tid=[171977], tls=0x7faa47ffb700, child_tidptr=0x7faa47ffb9d0) = 171977
...
[pid 171977] 03:22:12 getpid()          = 171280
...
[pid 171977] 03:22:12 getppid()         = 170039
[pid 171977] 03:22:12 getpid()          = 171280
[pid 171977] 03:22:12 getpid()          = 171280
```

From this I gather that 170039 is the parent of 171280 and this one in turn is the parent of 171977. How is the discrepancy of the last few lines where strace showing a different pid between brackets than the return value of the call?

I see that the second clone has the `CLONE_THREAD` flag:

```
       CLONE_THREAD (since Linux 2.4.0)
              If CLONE_THREAD is set, the child is placed in the same
              thread group as the calling process.
              (...)
              Internally, this shared PID is the so-called
              thread group identifier (TGID) for the thread group.
              Since Linux 2.4, calls to getpid(2) return the TGID of the
              caller.
```

I guess this might explain why the PID stays the same, but then what is the interpretation of what strace showing as "the PID" (which coincides with the return code of clone), i.e. 171977 in this example?

Answer (score 0):

> I see that the second clone has the `CLONE_THREAD` flag

> I guess this might explain why the PID stays the same

Correct.

> but then what is the interpretation of what strace showing as "the PID" (which coincides with the return code of clone), i.e. 171977 in this example?

The thread ID (TID). To see this, try adding some `gettid()` calls to the program you're tracing.